# CMake Cross Compilation secondary dependencies

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, ld

I have a program that compiles on my target machine (NVIDIA Jetson). Now I am trying to cross compile the same program on my laptop. I have a cross compiler and cloned the Jetson to use as a sysroot. I was following [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/l4t-multimedia/cross_platform_support.html) guide from NVIDIA. My program compiles, but fails at a linking step. I'm linking against a library (protobuf) and the linker can't find the dependencies of the library. I have produced a minimal example that demonstrates this.

main.cpp:

```
#include <google/protobuf/util/json_util.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    google::protobuf::util::JsonPrintOptions jsonOptions;
    jsonOptions.always_print_enums_as_ints = true;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(Test)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
target_include_directories(Test PRIVATE ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

On my target computer CMake generates and builds this fine, but when cross compiling on my laptop CMake generates the makefiles, and the build step fails with the error:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Test
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libm.so.6, needed by /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `deflate'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make:98: Test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

The required library (ZLIB) exists in my sysroot (/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so), but the linker can't find it.

My toolchain file is

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)


set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

What do I need to tell CMake so that the linker can find these secondary dependencies?

Comment: According to the error message, the `Protobuf` library you are trying to use is unusable for your cross-compilation environment. How do you compile (and install) that library? Do you use the same cross-compilation environment for it?

Comment: BTW, there is no reason to add the path, specified as `CMAKE_SYSROOT`, to `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` list: CMake does that automatically.

Comment: I compiled and installed the protobuf library from source according to the [readme](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md) before I cloned the image. Why do you think my installation of the library is unusable for cross compilation? I thought I just need to point CMake to its dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. When I cloned the image and mounted it on my laptop I broke all of the symlinks in the cloned image, such as `libz.so` which is why cmake couldn't find them. When I fixed the symlink cmake went on to complain about the next broken symlink in the same manner. I think there are too many symlinks to fix them manually, but at least now I know what went wrong.